# C# Templated Struct: Cannot implicitly convert

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, type-conversion, operator-overloading

Evening all, my problem is with the following:

```
public struct vector2D<T1>
{
    public T1 m_w;
    public T1 m_h;

    // Irrelevant stuff removed (constructor, other overloader's)

    public static bool operator !=(vector2D<T1> src, T1 dest)
    {
        return (((dynamic)src.m_w != (dynamic)dest) || ((dynamic)src.m_h != (dynamic)dest));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(vector2D<T1> src, T1 dest)
    {
        return (((dynamic)src.m_w != (dynamic)dest) || ((dynamic)src.m_h != (dynamic)dest));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(vector2D<T1> src, vector2D<T1> dest)
    {
        return (((dynamic)src.m_w != (dynamic)dest.m_w) || ((dynamic)src.m_h != (dynamic)dest.m_h));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(vector2D<T1> src, vector2D<T1> dest)
    {
        return Equals(src, dest);
    }
}
```

Now the error's I get is:

```
Error   1   Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'vector2D<int>' and 'vector2D<uint>'
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'vector2D<uint>' to 'vector2D<int>'
```

Now I know the compiler doesn't know how to "cast" with the following code fragment:

```
vector2D<uint>[] Something = new vector2D<uint>[2]; // Pretend it has values...
Dictonary<uint, vector2D<int>> AnotherThing = new Dictonary<uint, vector2D<int>>(); // Pretend it has values...

if (AnotherThing[0] != Something[0] ) { ... }

AnotherThing[0] = Something[0];
```

I've tried several thing and simply they either give me more errors and don't work or don't work. So my question is how would I go about doing the "casting"?

*Also might be good to mention, I usually program in C++ so C# has surprised me a few times. Also sorry in advance if the above code gives you nightmares.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need tell compiler how to convert type 'vector2D< uint >' to     'vector2D< int >'

```
public static implicit operator vector2D<T1>(vector2D<uint> src)
        {
            return new vector2D<T1>
                {
                    m_h = (T1)Convert.ChangeType(src.m_h, typeof(T1)),
                    m_w = (T1)Convert.ChangeType(src.m_w, typeof(T1)),
                };
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I tried something similar but it didn't work and I can see why it didn't, anyway thank you again.